# How can we refetch data using vuefire on route change?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I have a use case where I redirect the user to the same page but with a different route (/prices/usd, prices/yen, prices/eur etc...). I am using firestore and I am able to get data from firestore when the route is first visited but then onwards it doesn't fetch the fresh data even though route change if the page is same.

Answer (score 1):

Use [beforeRouteUpdate](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to bind to a different ref/document/collection